# IntelliJ not recognizing camelCase?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

[image]I just installed new version of IntelliJ, and it doesn't work with camelCase.

1. It only suggests in autocomplete snake_case.
2. When I double click on a variable name like `stringHolder` it will only select either `string` or `Holder`, but not the whole word.

Can someone assist on this? I went over all settings, but I couldn't solve this.

I even went to an old installation where it used to work properly, but now it also does the same. I can't explain it.

Comment: There are 2 options: one is specific for double click and another affects actual navigation by words with keyboard (left/right); but they work together: **1)** `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Mouse | Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click` and **2)** `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Use "CamelHumps" words`

Comment: @LazyOne it solved the double click on camelHumps but not the autocomplete of camelHumps methods..

Comment: I cannot really help with `snake_case` completion .. as I do not code in Java and do not use IntelliJ IDEA (I'm using another IDEA-based IDE -- PhpStorm). But I would suggest to look at Code Style settings -- based on what I read for other IDEA IDEs (like CLion) such settings for code generation/suggestion would be there.

Comment: Please screenshot demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @y.bedrov I attached an image to original question. I dont understand why it suggests me snake_case and not camelHump style.. it used to do it.

Comment: What is the method name? Is it in snake_case or camelHump style?

Comment: @y.bedrov its camelHump style

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?